# Impact of socket descriptor closed twice bug in multithreaded program

Tags: filesystems, c, multithreading

```
fd = open("file", O_RDONLY);
if (fd < 0) exit(1);

while((res = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)))){
if (res < 0){
close(fd);
fprintf(stderr, "Read error!\n");
break;
} else {
printf("Read %zd bytes\n", res);
}
}
close (fd);
```

In the single-threaded program this is an obvious bug: 'fd' is being closed twice. What could be the impact of this bug in a multithreaded program?

Comment: Nothing different from a single-threaded program: the second close() call will fail...

Comment: @prog-fh What if another thread opens a file or socket between the two `close` calls and gets the same descriptor?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz if it *opened* by any way the same resource (with `dup()`) for example, then the close call will make the first file descriptor unusable but the same resource will remain accessible by the other file-descriptor. But those two close calls don't apply to the same file-descriptor. Ah... OK I get it, you are talking about a race condition... Well, any could happen about anything, so why is it specific to this question?

Comment: @prog-fh Right. This code could be one half of a race condition with *any* other code that *any* other thread might be running. Who knows what that race condition will do?

Answer (score 1):

It could be anything. There's no reliable way to predict the effect of "contaminating" shared resources in a multi-threaded program.

The most obvious problem would be that you might close a socket that another thread had opened for some important purpose after your first close but before your second close. But there's no way you can predict what some piece code will do under those circumstances without understanding that code.

As just one example, you might prematurely normally terminate a connection to a remote server, causing the server to process a partial request instead of a complete one. There's no way to know what that partial request might do without understanding the protocol being used.

Here's an even worse scenario:

1. This thread closes descriptor 4.
2. A logging thread opens a local file and gets descriptor 4.
3. This thread closes descriptor 4 again. (The bug.)
4. Another thread opens a socket connection to an untrusted server and gets descriptor 4.
5. The logging thread runs again and writes sensitive information to descriptor 4.

Oops. We just sent highly-sensitive information to a random remote connection.

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, closing an already closed fd will just make your second `close()` return `EBADF` (fd isn't a valid open file descriptor). This is harmless.

On the other hand, in a multithreaded program, nothing guarantees you that the fd will not be reused, e.g. another thread is calling `open()` in the meantime between the two calls to `close()`. In that situation, your are unexpectedly closing the recently opened file, and this is harmful.

Answer (score 0):

> What could be the impact of this bug in a multithreaded program?

99.999% of the time, nothing; the second call to `close()` will fail with errno set to `EBADF` and life will go on.

The other .001% of the time, another thread will run and call `open()` in that exact instant between the executions of the two `close()` calls in your thread, and the other thread's `open()` call will return the same file-descriptor value that your `fd` local variable is set to (because the runtime is allowed to a re-use file-descriptor value after it has been closed)... then your thread will run again, and your second call to `close(fd)` will close the other thread's socket(!)

At that point, the other thread's networking calls that use that file-descriptor will start erroring out with `EBADF` (since it is trying to use a now-closed file-descriptor), and you will spend several unhappy hours/days/weeks trying to track down why your program's networking seems to randomly fail once in a blue moon.

Comment: Oh, it's much worse than that. They might not error out because another thread might open a different file or socket and get the same descriptor. They might *succeed* and send private information to an untrusted destination.

Comment: 1) The bad thread closes descriptor 4. 2) A victim thread opens descriptor 4. 3) The bad thread closes descriptor 4 again. 4) Another victim thread opens descriptor 4. 5) The first victim thread now writes to the connection the second victim thread opened thinking it's writing to whatever it opened.